# How can I make six buttons in Java inside one JFrame according to the instructions?

Tags: java

One button will make new file in the source, the second button will write what is in the text field on my JFrame inside that file, third button will do the exact opposite (write from that file to the text field), fourth button will delete text from the file, but not the file as a whole, fifth button will close the project window and the sixth one will delete the file. I need also that the layout around buttons needs to be colored and I would like if the project will tell me if the file was created/deleted too. I hope you can help me with that. I'm trying this all day but something still doesn't work. If I make some progress, I will comment here.

Edit:
For now I have this, but it doesn't show anything:

```java
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class project2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("New window");
        JButton button = new JButton ("Create");
        JButton writeto = new JButton ("Write to file");
        JButton close = new JButton ("Close");
        JButton delete = new JButton ("Delete file");
        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        JLabel text = new JLabel("Testing");
        JButton writefrom = new JButton("Write from file");
        JButton deletetext = new JButton("Delete");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(550,450);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, can you provide some information, what you have already done? Some parts of the code, please.

Comment: You need to add your JButtons and JLabels to a JPanel, and add the JPanel to the JFrame.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

Answer (score 0):

I did it somehow. I think I just didn't know how to make the buttons to appear, but after I found some functional parts of code on the internet, I did what I wanted. I think I was too rushed so I asked here, but hopefully that's okay. It would be good to make this project to take less rows, so more answers will be appreciated, but I'm already happy with the functionality.

Anyways here's my code for the six buttons:

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class project {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("New window");
        JButton button = new JButton ("Create");
        button.setBounds(80,20,100,30);
        JButton writeto = new JButton ("Write to file");
        writeto.setBounds(80,80,100,30);
        JButton close = new JButton ("Close");
        close.setBounds(80,140,100,30);
        JButton delete = new JButton ("Delete file");
        delete.setBounds(80,200,100,30);
        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        field.setBounds(80,380,100,30);
        JLabel text = new JLabel("Testing");
        text.setBounds(110,440,100,30);
        JButton writefrom = new JButton("Write from file");
        writefrom.setBounds(80,260,120,30);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(75,15,110,40);
        JButton deletetext = new JButton("Delete");
        deletetext.setBounds(80,320,100,30);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                File file = new File("file.txt");
                try {
                    if (file.createNewFile()) {
                        text.setText("Created");
                    }
                    else {
                        text.setText("Not created");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        writeto.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    FileWriter writeto = new FileWriter("file.txt");
                    writeto.write(field.getText());
                    writeto.close();
                    field.setText("");
                    text.setText("Task successful");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    text.setText("Task unsuccessful");
                }
            }
        });
        close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                File delete = new File("file.txt");
                if (delete.delete()) {
                    text.setText("Deleted");
                }
                else {
                    text.setText("Not deleted");
                }
            }
        });
        writefrom.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                File writefrom = new File("file.txt");
                try {
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(writefrom);
                    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                        String data = scanner.nextLine();
                        field.setText(data);
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        deletetext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    FileWriter deletetext = new FileWriter("file.txt");
                    deletetext.write("");
                    deletetext.close();
                    field.setText("");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    text.setText("Task unsuccessful");
                }
            }
        });
        window.add(button);
        window.add(writeto);
        window.add(close);
        window.add(delete);
        window.add(field);
        window.add(text);
        window.add(writefrom);
        window.add(panel);
        window.setLayout(null);
        window.add(deletetext);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(300,600);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my rewrite of your application. Note the following:

- You should almost always use a layout manager (rather than setting the layout to null and calling method `setBounds`). In the below code I use [BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html).
- After you read or writer a file, you should close it. In the below code I use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure that the file is closed.
- Rather than using anonymous, inner classes to implement the `ActionListener`s, I use [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Project2 {
    private static final String  FILE_NAME = "file.txt";
    private JLabel  text;
    private JTextField  field;

    private void addComponentToPanel(Component cmpt, JPanel panel) {
        panel.add(cmpt);
        panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));
    }

    private void close(ActionEvent event) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("New Window");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.add(createPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton createButton(String text,
                                 int mnemonic,
                                 String tooltip,
                                 Dimension prefSize,
                                 ActionListener listener) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        if (prefSize != null) {
            button.setMaximumSize(prefSize);
        }
        if (mnemonic > 0) {
            button.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
        }
        if (tooltip != null  &&  !tooltip.isEmpty()) {
            button.setToolTipText(tooltip);
        }
        button.addActionListener(listener);
        return button;
    }

    private void createFile(ActionEvent event) {
        File file = new File(FILE_NAME);
        try {
            if (file.createNewFile()) {
                text.setText("Created");
            }
            else {
                text.setText("Not created");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private JPanel createPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
        panel.setLayout(layout);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        JButton widest = createButton("Write from file",
                                      KeyEvent.VK_F,
                                      "Display file contents.",
                                      null,
                                      this::writeFrom);
        Dimension dim = widest.getPreferredSize();
        addComponentToPanel(createButton("Create",
                                         KeyEvent.VK_R,
                                         "Create file.",
                                         dim,
                                         this::createFile),
                            panel);
        addComponentToPanel(createButton("Write to file",
                                         KeyEvent.VK_T,
                                         "Write entered text to file.",
                                         dim,
                                         this::writeTo),
                            panel);
        addComponentToPanel(createButton("Close",
                                         KeyEvent.VK_C,
                                         "Close application.",
                                         dim,
                                         this::close),
                            panel);
        addComponentToPanel(createButton("Delete file",
                                         KeyEvent.VK_E,
                                         "Delete the file.",
                                         dim,
                                         this::delete),
                            panel);
        addComponentToPanel(widest, panel);
        addComponentToPanel(createButton("Delete",
                                         KeyEvent.VK_D,
                                         "Delete file contents.",
                                         dim,
                                         this::deleteText),
                            panel);
        field = new JTextField();
        addComponentToPanel(field, panel);
        text = new JLabel("Testing");
        text.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        addComponentToPanel(text, panel);
        return panel;
    }

    private void delete(ActionEvent event) {
        File delete = new File(FILE_NAME);
        if (delete.delete()) {
            text.setText("Deleted");
        }
        else {
            text.setText("Not deleted");
        }
    }

    private void deleteText(ActionEvent event) {
        try (FileWriter deletetext = new FileWriter(FILE_NAME)) {
            deletetext.write("");
            deletetext.close();
            field.setText("");
        }
        catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            text.setText("Task unsuccessful");
        }
    }

    private void writeFrom(ActionEvent event) {
        File writefrom = new File(FILE_NAME);
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(writefrom)) {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = scanner.nextLine();
                field.setText(data);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void writeTo(ActionEvent event) {
        try (FileWriter writeto = new FileWriter(FILE_NAME)) {
            writeto.write(field.getText());
            writeto.close();
            field.setText("");
            text.setText("Task successful");
        }
        catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            text.setText("Task unsuccessful");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Project2 proj2 = new Project2();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> proj2.createAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```

This is how the GUI looks when I run the above code.

[image: screen capture of GUI]